# How to extract the String in these 3 cases using Regex with Java

Tags: java, regex

I´m dealing with one problem. I have three strings that I want to extract only the String.

```
Observações da #{loginBean.centralCreditoRole ? 'central de crédito' : 'loja'}

#{resource['images:header_logo_client.png']}

#{propostaCartaoBean.pojo.inss.exclusaoDataprevAgendada ? 'Sim' : 'Não'}
```

In line 1 the output will be 3 strings, `Observações da`, `central de crédito`, `loja`. Line 2 will be blank and Line 3 `Sim` and `Não`.

I got  line 2 like this `teste.replaceAll("\\#.+?\\}", "");`

Is it possible to deal this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is not sufficient enough to understand your need. However, you can try this example:

```
String input = "Observações da #{loginBean.centralCreditoRole ? 'central de crédito' : 'loja'}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)#.*?\\?\\s*(?:'(.*?)(?<!\\\\)'\\s+:\\s+'(.*?)(?<!\\\\)')?");

Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}
```

This one is showing how it can parse the three portions from your first input.